# Maximized window on both displays on OS X 10.8.3

Tags: macos, display, window-manager

I have a dual monitor setup on the Mac. I want to work on a tool, in full screen, on display 1 and simultaneously check few things, on Final Cut Pro, on display 2.

When I maximize the tool in  display 1, I can't see the FCP in display 2.

Is there any third party tool to solve this, or is it an OS X limitation.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2

These are the [support instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351) for using multiple monitors with Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and earlier. You will likely want to use the **Extended Desktop** Settings. If you still doesn't let you see the other app, then check to see if FCP has an Always On Top setting which may be turned off, and don't have the apps set to full-screen mode.

UPDATE

This solution will only work if you are running Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) or later. (Apologies as I missed in your question that 10.8 was Mountain Lion and not Mavericks).

[image]

If you do find it, then set that. Then go to one Desktop and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on the FCP icon in the Dock and under Options, select This Desktop.

Then go to another desktop, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on the other apps icon and under options select This Desktop.

Then you should be able to go to one monitor and select the FCP Desktop, move to the second monitor and select the other Apps Desktop and that should display both apps on the respective monitors.

This is Apple's support page for [Multiple Displays](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202780).

Comment: No, i don't have the 'Display have separate spaces' option on the mission control like you do (screenshot). Is there a way i can enable it or make it show up on the pane.

Comment: Are you the admin on your Mac? Because otherwise I have no idea why that wouldn't be there unless something in your display settings is affecting the Mission Control Settings. Usually then it would only be grayed out... Try disconnecting one of the monitors and restarting and see if it is still missing.

Comment: I'm the admin .
Disconnected the monitor. Restarted. But same thing   :(

Comment: That sounds like an ask Apple question... I guess if you have a good, recent back, you can go ahead and try and doing a reinstall of the OS... That seems extreme....

Comment: @Mrityunjoy, The 'Display have separate spaces' option is not available in OS X 10.8, which you're using, and was not introduced until OS X 10.9.

Comment: @user3439894. You are correct. The Apple support site has it for Mavericks. I got confused with the numbering and forgot that 10.8 was Mountain Lion.

Comment: Yes! looks like it is an OS limitation.
Worked fine on 10.10, will upgrade. Thanks

Comment: I think you will like Yosemite. Apple has added some nice new features since Mountain Lion. Enjoy!